Auditing files and folders (multiple folders/files, MULTIPLE accounts!)
I'm trying to apply auditing on folders and files in Windows 11 Pro. I've found a script online and I modified it in order to apply auditing on many folder or files that are read from an input file (AuditedFolders.txt). Audit users/accounts are read from a different file (AuditUsers.txt). This required two foreach loops (internal loops goes through folders or files and the external loop switches an user from a file). The problem is I wasn't able to ADD audit user. Each time the script finishes, one audit user is applied to a folder and it's the last one from the file AuditUsers.txt. Replacing is done instead of adding even if the .AddAuditRule method is used. I know that very similar problem was mentioned in few questions on SO but it referred to AccessRule and it's a different thing. Inspection tab has "Add" button so there must be a way to add audit user instead of replacing. I appreciate any ideas how to solve this.
Thanks in advance.
Write-Host 'Enabling Auditing'
Write-Host '-----------------'
Set-MpPreference -EnableControlledFolderAccess Enabled
Write-Host 'Setting auditing for files and folders'
Write-Host '--------------------------------------'
$TargetFolders = Get-Content C:\Input\AuditedFolders.txt
$AuditUsers = Get-Content C:\Input\AuditUsers.txt
$AuditRules = 'FullControl'
$InheritType = 'ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit'
$AuditType = 'Success'

foreach ($AuditUser in $AuditUsers) {
    $AccessRule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAuditRule($AuditUser, $AuditRules, $InheritType, 'None', $AuditType)
    Write-Host 'Setting auditing for the following account', $AuditUser
    foreach ($TargetFolder in $TargetFolders) {
        $ACL = Get-Acl $TargetFolder
        $ACL.AddAuditRule($AccessRule)
        Write-Host 'Processing >', $TargetFolder
        $ACL | Set-Acl $TargetFolder
    }
}

Tried searching in all Powershell Set-Acl commands but no luck.

Not sure if this is a bug or expected however, once you set the ACL object and then try to add a new rule the previous one is lost as you're experiencing currently. Solution to the problem is to first get the ACL object, then add all rules with .AddAuditRule as you're doing and lastly set it.
For this the recommended approach is to change the outer loop, instead of looping through each user loop through each folder and in the inner loop add each rule:
$rulesToAdd = foreach ($AuditUser in $AuditUsers) {
    [System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAuditRule]::new(
        $AuditUser, $AuditRules, $InheritType, 'None', $AuditType)
}

foreach ($TargetFolder in $TargetFolders) {
    Write-Host 'Processing >', $TargetFolder
    $acl = Get-Acl $TargetFolder

    # first add all rules to the acl object
    foreach ($rule in $rulesToAdd) {
        Write-Host 'Adding auditing for the following account', $rule.IdentityReference
        $acl.AddAuditRule($rule)
    }

    # then set it
    $acl | Set-Acl $TargetFolder
}


$acl = Get-Acl $TargetFolder -Audit

Look at the bold text.
SACL entry was not imported from get-Acl.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
